# I am able to access and modify the class attributes through staticmethod of same class

Tags: python, static-methods

I [read](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/):

> - A static method is also a method which is bound to the class and not the object of the class.
> - A static method can’t access or modify class state.

Code Snippet as below

```
class tester:
    v1 = 10

    def __init__ ( self,  v2 ):
        self.v2 = v2

    @classmethod
    def test_class_method(cls):
        print (type(cls))
        print(cls.__name__)
        print(cls.v1)

    @staticmethod
    def test_static_method ( v3 ):
        print (tester.v1)
        tester.v1 = 20
        print (tester.v1)
```

But i am able to access the class attribute and modify it through staticmethods as seen below

```
>>> t1  = class_methods.tester (30)
>>> 
>>> class_methods.tester.test_class_method()
<class 'type'>
tester
10

>>> class_methods.tester.test_static_method(40)
10
20
>>>
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/

Comment: A static method doesn't have an argument for its class or instance the way a classmethod or instance method do, but you can still access anything outside of it like you could in any normal function.  In your incomplete example above, you access `tester` in your static method.  If you access and modify this as a global, then you can modify it as one.

Comment: then how is different then class method , apart from class method takes the first paramter as class itself ?

Comment: Ok, the wording there is a bit vague. It means that a static method doesn't generally know which class it belongs to. In your example you specifically tell it to modify an attribute of the `tester` class. With a `classmethod` you don't have to tell that. That's pretty much the only difference.

Comment: @srp: That's the difference.  And it's a big one.  Receiving a cls argument gives you access to the class that classmethod is bound to.  In a staticmethod, you can directly use the named class (i.e. def staticmethod(...): return MyClass.property) but if you subclass MyClass, then staticmethod would never know what class actually called it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access `tester` class as a global from any function.  The difference with `classmethod` is that it receives `cls` as a first argument, which is the class the method is bound to.  This can make a difference if you subclass the class with the static method.

```
 class Tester():
    @classmethod
    def clsmeth(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)
 
    @staticmethod
    def staticmeth():
        print(Tester.__name__)

 class Sub(Tester):
    pass
```

Then your functions would behave differently.

```
 >>> Tester.clsmeth()
 Tester
 >>> Tester.staticmeth()
 Tester
 >>> Sub.clsmeth()
 Sub
 >>> Sub.staticmeth()
 Tester
```

Comment: Thank you @saquintes , that beautifully answers the difference.